# Assignment operator overloading for templated matrix class

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, assignment-operator

I am implementing assignment operator function for a template matrix class.
It should take care of different datatype matrix assignments. eg Integer matrix is assigned to a double matrix.
for that i have following declaration:

```
template<class U> MyMatrix<T>& operator= (const MyMatrix<U> &rhs) {...}
```

My problem is, if i implement the fuction within class declaration, it works. But if i implement it outside the class declaration like,

```
template<class T, class U> MyMatrix<T>& MyMatrix<T>::operator= (const MyMatrix<U> &rhs){...}
```

i get following error:

```
error: no declaration matches ‘MyMatrix<T>& MyMatrix<T>::operator=(const MyMatrix<U>&)’
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: An out-of-class definition would have to look like `template<class T> template<class U> MyMatrix<T>& //etc.` - you have a template within a template, not a template that takes 2 template parameters

Comment: @UnholySheep, can you please suggest resources where i can learn more about templates? Thanks

Comment: The only resource I can think of off the top of my head would be "Modern C++ Design" by Andrei Alexandrescu - but that is already a quite advanced text on templates. Otherwise I have mainly learnt by reading and working with code written by more experienced programmers

Answer (score 1):

When providing out of class definition of a member template you've to provide the *template parameter clause* correspondimg to both the class template as well as the member template as shown below:

```
template<class T> // parameter clause for class template 
template<class U> // parameter clause for member template
MyMatrix<T>& MyMatrix<T>::operator= (const MyMatrix<U> &rhs)
{  // code here
}
```